# Объединить значения с одинаковыми id

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно объединить значения с одинаковыми id. Есть массив:

```
$data = Array (
0 => Array ('id' => 11, 'description' => Array(Array('text' => 'yellow'))), 
1 => Array ('id' => 11, 'description' => Array(Array('text' => 'red'))), 
2 => Array ('id' => 22, 'description' => Array(Array('text' => 'green'))), 
);
```

Нужно получить:

```
$data = Array (
0 => Array ('id' => 11, 'description' => Array(Array('text' => 'yellow, red'))), 
1 => Array ('id' => 22, 'description' => Array(Array('text' => 'green'))), 
);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться техникой reduce-map:

1. С помощью array_reduce группируете одинаковые записи, агрегируя необходимые данные нужным образом.
2. С помощью array_map формируете необходимый итоговый формат(implode cобранного массива текстов, например)

Пример с чуть более простой структурой:

```
$data = [
 ['id' => 111, 'text' => 'yellow'],
 ['id' => 111, 'text' => 'red'],
 ['id' => 112, 'text' => 'green'],
];

$result = array_map(function($item) {return [
    'id' => $item['id'],
    'text' => implode(', ', $item['colors']),
];}, array_reduce($data, function($reduced, $item){
    if (!isset($reduced[$item['id']])) $reduced[$item['id']] = $item;
    $reduced[$item['id']]['colors'][] = $item['text'];
    return $reduced;
}, []));
```

[3v4l demo](https://3v4l.org/QCRV6)

Comment: Это неважно. Вам просто нужно немного модифицировать reducer. Я этого сделать не могу, потому что в вопросе недостаточно данных. Например, что делать, если в массиве description будет более одного элемента?

Comment: А в description не будет более одного элемента. Это атрибуты в opencart, т.е. в description сделан массив для передачи language_id, но на сайте будет только 1 язык.

Comment: И тем не менее, я указал алгоритм, а полное решение вашей конкретной задачи я позволю себе оставить вам или другим участникам.

Answer (score -1):

Так не делают

```
$data=array(
    array("id"=>"111","description"=>array(array(
          "text"=>"голубой"))
    ),
    array("id"=>"111","description"=>array(array(
          "text"=>"желтый"))
    ),
    array("id"=>"112","description"=>array(array(
          "text"=>"yellow"))
    ),
    array("id"=>"112","description"=>array(array(
          "text"=>"green"))
    ));

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $ser=$value['id'];

for($i = 1; $i<count($data); $i++){
if($ser==$data[$i]['id']){

    array_push($data[$i-1]['description'][0],$value['description'][0]['text'] );
}
}
}

print_r($data);
```